# Django change upgrade MSSQL database

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a Django app that was running without any problem with SQL server 2008,
I have an issue like this after I upgraded the MS SQL server 2008 into 2019.
I didn't change anything in the code but when I'm calling the DB, I face this error:

> 42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate dbo.REGEXP_LIKE", or the name is ambiguous.
> (4121) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
> Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here, the database you are connected to doesn't have the  the user-defined function or aggregate `dbo.REGEXP_LIKE` on it. It seems that when you migrated, you did not migrate that function.

Comment: SQL Server never had a `REGEXP_LIKE` function. It doesn't have any regular expression functions. It seems someone created a custom method with that name in SQL Server 2008 which wasn't migrated to the new database.

Comment: `I upgraded the MS SQL server 2008 into 2019` -> can you better describe this process?

Comment: *Presumably* the function is a CLR function, as SQL Server has *no native support* for Regex, and so the only way to get support for it is with CLR objects.

Comment: Instead of trying to copy what is almost certainly an obsolete function, perhaps you should ensure that `mssql-django` is installed?

Comment: @Larnu or worse. If you google for `Django REGEXP_LIKE` you'll find some hideous COM calls to the VBScript Regex object.

Comment: [Microsoft's mssq-django](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django/blob/master/mssql/creation.py) does use SQLCLR and should be *several* orders of magnitude faster than any implementation that used COM through `sp_OACreate`. Plus, it's supported by Microsoft so there's someone to blame *and* fix problems if something goes wrong

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't upgrade the DB. The administration team took a backup and restore it on their new SQL server without letting us know. I'm new in Django and this is why I don't know if this error is because of a custom SQL function or a feature in Django DB manager  that is related to the database version.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker the admin team took a backup from SQL server 2008 and restored it on SQL 2019. I have the functions there, but the Django app can't find it...

Comment: My guess: it is a synonym that points to (or a function that references another function in) a different database, and that database didn't get restored. Or Django simply isn't pointing at the same place you're looking.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker I checked the database and there are tables with data the same as the old db. it's been resotred but maybe not completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was about Regex on Django and SQL server.
SQL server doesn't support Regex. So, You have to add an assembly to patch the SQL server.
To do so, You need to have a Class library in .netframework to create a .dll file. Here is the code for the class library:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    private const RegexOptions DefaultRegExOptions =
        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline;

    [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
    public static SqlInt32 REGEXP_LIKE(SqlString input, SqlString pattern, SqlInt32 caseSensitive)
    {
        RegexOptions options = DefaultRegExOptions;
        if (caseSensitive==0)
            options |= RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

        return Regex.IsMatch(input.Value, pattern.Value, options) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Then you need to configure your DB using this SQL script:

```
-- Use the proper database
use [DBNAME]
GO

-- Enable CLR in this database
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'clr strict security',0;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'clr strict security',1;
GO

-- Create the assembly in the database from the path can this be done via a file path?
CREATE ASSEMBLY regex_clr from ' your DLL file location, for example: C:\mehdi\regex_clr.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO

-- Pull in the User Defined Function from the assembly
create function REGEXP_LIKE
(
    @input nvarchar(4000),
    @pattern nvarchar(4000),
    @caseSensitive int
) 
RETURNS INT  AS 
EXTERNAL NAME regex_clr.UserDefinedFunctions.REGEXP_LIKE
GO
```

then your db would work with REGEX properly.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server never had a `REGEXP_LIKE function`. It doesn't have any regular expression functions. It seems someone created a custom method with that name in SQL Server 2008 which wasn't migrated to the new database.

The SQL Server backend is provided by the [mssql-django](https://pypi.org/project/mssql-django/) package. [The source](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django/blob/master/mssql/creation.py) shows that the module installs a SQLCLR assembly that implements the regular expression functionality.

Regular expressions can't take advantage of indexes *in any database*. Even in databases that have functions like `REGEXP_LIKE`, no indexes are used and the queries have to scan the entire table. That's why databases offer separate Full Text Search indexes and functions, and why CMS and document management systems use software like Elastic